# Aggregation and feature extraction at the same time using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aggregate

i have this dataset

```
+---------+------+------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|    LCLid|season|       sum(KWH/hh)|         avg(KWH/hh)|Acorn_grouped|
+---------+------+------------------+--------------------+-------------+
|MAC000023|autumn|4067.4269999000007| 0.31550007755972703|            4|
|MAC000128|spring| 961.2639999999982| 0.10876487893188484|            2|
|MAC000012|summer| 121.7360000000022|0.027548314098212765|            0|
|MAC000053|autumn| 2289.498000000006| 0.17883908764255632|            2|
|MAC000121|spring| 1893.635999900008| 0.21543071671217384|            1|
```

for every consumerID we have the sum and avg consumption in every month, acron grouped is fixed for each consumer

i want to aggregate according to the id and in the same time extract those new features and have round numbers to finally have this data

```
+---------+-------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------
|    LCLid|Acorn_grouped|autumn_avg(KWH/hh) |autumn_sum(KWH/hh)|autumn_max(KWH/hh)|spring_avg(KWH/hh)
+---------+-------------+-------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------
|MAC000023|            4|                   |                  |                  |
|MAC000128|            2|                   |                  |                  |
|MAC000012|            0|                   |                  |                  |
|MAC000053|            2|                   |                  |                  |
|MAC000121|            1|                   |                  |                  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a pivot:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

result = df.groupBy('LCLid', 'Acorn_grouped') \
           .pivot('season') \
           .agg(
               F.round(F.first('sum(KWH/hh)')).alias('sum(KWH/hh)'), 
               F.round(F.first('avg(KWH/hh)')).alias('avg(KWH/hh)')
           ).fillna(0)   # replace nulls with zero - 
                         # you can skip this if you want to keep nulls
```

Comment: thank you so much it works , have you an idea how to applicate the round function during this process

Comment: @eyabaklouti I have added the round function